# How to find the mean of multiple columns based on a second dataset?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, across

### Problem

I need to use a dictionary dataset to determine which columns from a different dataset I should calculate the mean.

### Data

I will illustrate my case with the `iris` dataset (a dataset already in R).

I have two datasets:

1. The actual data - like `iris` (however the col names is basically a1, a2, a3, a4...).
2. The dictionary for the former indicates what each `iris` column indicates. The column `feature` in the `dictionary_iris` is the grouping variable, and it would also be part of the name for the new variables (e.g., the new variable would be called `Sepal_mean`, or `Petal_mean`).

#### Iris dataset

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% as_tibble()

  # # A tibble: 150 x 5
  # Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
  # <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
  # 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
  # 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
  # 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
  # 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
  # 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
  # 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
  # 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
  # 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
  # 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
  # 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
  # # ... with 140 more rows
```

### Dictionary Dataset

```
dictionary_iris <- tibble(variables = names(iris)) %>% 
  separate(variables, into = c("feature", "measure"), remove = FALSE)

dictionary_iris

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# variables    feature measure
# <chr>        <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 Sepal.Length Sepal   Length 
# 2 Sepal.Width  Sepal   Width  
# 3 Petal.Length Petal   Length 
# 4 Petal.Width  Petal   Width  
# 5 Species      Species NA
```

### Expected Output

I know how to do that manually (see below), but I would like to automatize this process because I have a dataframe with more than 300 columns and want to take 23 different means across those columns.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Sepal_mean = mean(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), na.rm = TRUE),
         Petal_mean = mean(c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), na.rm = TRUE))


# # A tibble: 150 x 7
# # Rowwise: 
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal_mean Petal_mean
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa        4.3        0.8 
# 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa        3.95       0.8 
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa        3.95       0.75
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa        3.85       0.85
# 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa        4.3        0.8 
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa        4.65       1.05
# 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa        4          0.85
# 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa        4.2        0.85
# 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa        3.65       0.8 
# 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa        4          0.8 
# # ... with 140 more rows
```

I have the impression that I can do that with `dplyr::mutate()` and `dplyr::across()` or with some `dplyr::map()` function. But I got quite lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to use 'feature' column as a grouping, then `split` the 'dictionary_iris' by the 'feature' column (removed the last row (`-5`) as it is not numeric column, loop over the `list` with `imap`, `transmute` to create the column in 'iris' with the `rowMeans` of those column name, and bind with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- imap_dfc(split(dictionary_iris$variables[-5], 
        dictionary_iris$feature[-5]),
   ~ iris %>%
      transmute(!! str_c(.y, "_mean") := 
         rowMeans(across(all_of(.x)), na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
    bind_cols(iris, .)
```

-output

```
> head(out)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal_mean Sepal_mean
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa       0.80       4.30
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa       0.80       3.95
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa       0.75       3.95
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa       0.85       3.85
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa       0.80       4.30
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa       1.05       4.65
```

Comment: It worked great. Could you explain what `!!` and `:=` are doing in transmute? and why not using `mutate()`  instead of `transmute()` and `bind_cols()`?

Comment: @RuamPimentel `mutate` returns the entire dataset along with the new column added whereas `transmute` only returns the column added.  So, if you use `mutate`, we return the `iris` dataset replicated twice in the loop.  Instead, here we return only the columns need and `bind` with the orignal data outside.  The `=` wouldn't allow an expresssion to be parsed on the lhs, whereas `:=` does evaluate to create the column

Answer (score 0):

```
iris_means <- iris %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, Species)) %>% 
  mutate(name = gsub("\\..*", "", name)) %>% 
  group_by(id, name) %>% 
  summarise(val = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  filter(name %in% !!dictionary_iris$feature) %>% 
  pivot_wider(-name, values_from = "val", names_glue = "{.name}_mean")

iris %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(iris_means) %>% 
  select(-id)


Joining, by = "id"
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Petal_mean Sepal_mean
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       0.80       4.30
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa       0.80       3.95
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa       0.75       3.95
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa       0.85       3.85
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa       0.80       4.30
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa       1.05       4.65
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, your response doesn't use the dictionary dataset. I see that is not needed for the `iris` dataset because the column names already contain the information that we need. However, this option is not generalizable for datasets that contain random names for the columns. Also, it doesn't reproduce the expected output that keeps the original data.

Comment: I understand, I've updated my answer in case it could be of any help.

Comment: I get the following error from the first syntax: `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `name` doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems we have to delete `-name` argument from `pivot_wider()`

Comment: Also, this part: `mutate(name = gsub("\\..*", "", name))` should be based on the `dictionary_iris` to generalize to other datasets.